# Deal with multiple titles, descriptions and keywords in Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, mongodb, orm, mongoid

I've an element who can have one or some titles, one or some descriptions and one or some keywords list. From the web view, we have a some kind of "add alternative title" buttons. I was wondering what is the right way to design this kind of schema in Mongoid.

I was thinking implementing one of this 3 solutions (Maybe sorted from the worst to the best):

1) Add fields up to a reasonable number

```
 class Video
     include Mongoid::Document
     field :alt_title_1
     field :alt_title_2
     field :alt_title_3
     field :alt_description_1
     field :alt_description_2
     field :alt_description_3
     field :alt_keywords_1
     field :alt_keywords_2
     field :alt_keywords_3
 end
```

2) Or, define this field as type: Array

```
 class Video
     include Mongoid::Document
     field :titles, type: Array
     field :descriptions, type: Array
     field :keywords, type: Array
 end
```

3) Or, having complex relationship

```
 class Video
     include Mongoid::Document
     embeds_many :titles, :descriptions, :keywords
 end

 class Title
     include Mongoid::Document
     embedded_in :video
     field :value
 end

 class Description
     include Mongoid::Document
     embedded_in :video
     field :value
 end

 class Keyword
     include Mongoid::Document
     embedded_in :video
     field :value, type: Array
 end
```

What do you think make more sense? Is there a better solution out there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I like 2 the most. These are just strings so it doesn't make sense to have multiple models.

Comment: I see, do you know how to make validation works with the array? I am using 3) only for that.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for number 2 too for the same reasons as Jeff. If I had to validate the inputs I would make a custom validation.